# SQL Server Optimization: Function in SELECT calculated before or after WHERE Clause?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I was just wondering if in SQL Server if in a statement like this:

```
SELECT A.Field1, dbo.someFunction(A.IdentifierID) As Field 
FROM Table A WHERE A.IdentifierID = 1000
```

Will it call someFunction for all the rows in the table, or will it call it once?

Thanks!

Comment: try it and see which is faster!

Answer (score 3):

It will be called for every row of result

Answer (score 1):

the count of calls depends on the resulted rows, i.e, if the output of the query 100 row the it will be called 100 times, not for all rows in the table

but if it were in the where clause, the it will evaluated for each row

Answer (score 0):

Will call it for every row, but since you are selecting a specific one (or so it seems), it will be called once on your example.

Answer (score 0):

As vlad commented you should try it and see. There are of course two options:

1. It could call it just once knowing IdentifierID will always be 1000.

but that might not be the right thing...

1. It could call it for each row - maybe the function has side-effects?

I strongly suspect #2.

Answer (score 0):

Compliant SQL servers are supposed to *appear* as if they apply the WHERE clause before they apply the SELECT clause.  So it should *appear* to evaluate the function at most once for each row that satisfies `WHERE A.IdentifierID = 1000`.

But database engines are free to optimize however they like, as long as they give you the same results the standards require. So in your case, since you're selecting a single ID number, it might only have to evaluate the function once.